# ASP.NET Web Pages and AD Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Is it possible to authenticate a user with Active Directory membership using the web pages flavor of asp.net? What I've noticed from most examples I've seen online is that webpages uses the simple membership provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've successfully used this setup in the past to authenticate using Active Directory on .net web pages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx

**UPDATE:**

The previous link will work for "Web Forms"/framework 2.0. This seems to be the equivalent for "Web Pages": http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/216/Windows-Authentication-With-ASP.NET-Web-Pages

I've never used the method described for Web Pages, but looking through the code and comparing it, it seems to be doing the same thing, which is disabling the default SimpleMembership authentication and using AD instead. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using the asp.net web pages technology and not web forms. http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Comment: Sorry, I actually didn't even know there was officially something called "ASP.NET Web Pages". I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use a custom log in page with your asp.net application with Forms Authentication, you're able to use the AD pretty easily. Under Forms Authentication in your Web.config, place the membership provider that is listed below.
Then in your connectionStrings, place the AD Service connection below with your information. After that, since you will have more pages, you want to make sure that they cannot just simply navigate to those pages. By denying the users to that page by using the . Then whoever has an Active directory account can access that site. It's suggested to use Roles to deny users access to certain parts of the website. You can also change the authentication mode from "Forms" to "Windows" and this uses an AD log in. I needed it to be a little more secure because some people at my company do not need to see this website. To do this, I verify the username against an SQL database. As long as the username matches the one in the database, then they are allowed to log in. I hope this helps!

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <!--Membership provider for Active Directory-->
    <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,  System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADService" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
  </providers>
</membership>


<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADService" connectionString="LDAP://YOURDOMAINNAME/OU=YOURORGANIZATIONALGROUP,DC=YOURDOMAINCONTROLLER,DC=net" />
  </connectionStrings>


//This deny's all users who do not have an AD account. 
<location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: This should work. It uses the web.config to do that authentication. So as long as your use a web.config with your asp.net web pages. The web.config is xml, so I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work.